# Mac OSX permissions

Tags: macos, vpn, user-accounts, administrator, sudo

Please, before jumping to much appreciated answer, please read this, as my problem is not related to files and folders permissions (`chmod` and `chown`).

I have a Mac, with 2 user, one is an admin, and the 2nd one is regular user, with no sudo power. Before setting up the 2nd user, I had a vpn set up, the admin user have no problem accessing the VPN, but the regular user can't access the VPN, as it specifically says only admin can connect the VPN, please note that this not a message from the VPN server, because when I make the user as a sudoer he can connect to the VPN.

Any idea, how I can while the user have no sudo power still be able to connect to VPN.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a *nix guy, not a OSX guy, so I'm speaking from a position of commonalities rather than specifics.

Admin rights are required to set up the virtual network interface that the VPN uses.

You probably can't get around requiring at least some sudo rights for this, but you should be able to figure out exactly what commands the VPN setup is using and allow only those in the sudoers file.